# Stack Exchange inbox shows incorrect number of answers for a question

Tags: bug, questions, answers, stack-exchange, global-inbox

[A question I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/what-if-the-answers-of-a-historical-locked-question-become-obsolete) has only three answers, but my Stack Exchange inbox shows 6 answers on *What if the answers of a historical locked question become obsolete?*:

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You probably have 6 answers. You just can't see some deleted ones (and neither can I) because we don't have 10k reputation.

Comment: @Ben: there are no deleted answers on that question (at least none that 10k users can see).

Comment: Could it be that comments and answers are lumped together in that counter?

Comment: @DanielFischer If that is true then I'd call this a display bug in the notification test then.

Comment: @DanielFischer - unlikely. I just had the same bug in SFF.SE and had TWO separate notifications; one of comments; one for (incorrectly counted) answers.