# Inbox number wrong?

Tags: feature-request, support, bug, global-inbox

**Edit:** Feature-request: Add a "stack count" before stacked messages to reduce possible confusion. Like

> [2] comment on QUESTION

Whenever someone posts an answer to your question, or a comment under your post, or a comment that mentions you, you get a inbox message, represented on top right with a number on red background. The number is right how many message you've got and unread.
However I often see the number displayed is wrong, mostly shifted up by 1. That is, for example, I have 2 new items, but the number shows 3 (as shown below, I *definitely* have read those 9 hr ago items).
I'm not quite clear how to reproduce this issue, but it seems like this issue occurs more frequently in this way:
1. Get 2 or more inbox items
2. Read some of them, but not all, then quit
3. Get some more inbox items
Now the number is *possibly* wrong.

> [image]

Comment: Did you use your browser's back button? This will always show the number of notifications you had when you first loaded the page.

Comment: How many notifications now? Some of the notifications stack and you are only shown one in your inbox. (This means that when, e.g. two people have an entire discussion in the comments on one of your posts, the number says 30, but the inbox shows only one message.)

Comment: Here, let me add another comment, to demonstrate.

Comment: @Laurel Post an answer, please. You're right.

Comment: You should post a new question for the Feature Request. Also, they used to show numbers, like you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156246/323179).

Comment: @Laurel Can I [edit] this question thoroughly to make it a feature request?

Comment: This is basically still a thing, though it's more noticeable with the [inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251) (and has been pointed out in the answers there) due to notifications being marked read individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is correct, but not all of the inbox items are shown because they stack. You will only see a summary of the last item in each stack.

This feature is most obvious and helpful when people are chatting in the comments one of your posts, since it only takes up one inbox slot.

You can see all your messages, unstacked [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).