# Can't flag historically locked questions

Tags: support, status-completed, flags, retag-request, historical-lock

I know, it doesn't make much sense to flag a question or answer post once a question is **historically** locked, because in theory nothing should need to change in the question ever again.

Recently, the [education](/questions/tagged/education) tag was cleaned up.  However, there are two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935951/what-are-some-advanced-software-development-topics-every-developer-should-know), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143760/what-books-should-i-read-to-have-an-undergraduate-education-in-computer-science)) that still have the tag associated with it, which is preventing it from getting cleaned up in the nightly cleanup.  Since the questions are historically locked, I can't even flag them for moderator attention.

Two questions:

1. Can a moderator please remove the tag from these questions so that it can get cleaned up?
2. Is there a more appropriate way to flag these questions for attention than bringing it up on Meta?  Or is this such an edge case that it's just easier to bring it up here instead of doing something silly like flagging some other question and then including your request in the "Other" notes?

Comment: Asking here on Meta or in chat (when there is a mod roaming freely) appears to be the proper way to do this.

Comment: *Recently, the education tag was cleaned up.*  Yes, I wonder how that happened?

Comment: Also, [number one there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935951/what-are-some-advanced-software-development-topics-every-developer-should-know) has one tag--training.  That needs to go away as well.  Not sure what to tag that monstrosity.

Comment: *Yes, I wonder how that happened?* The world may never know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have removed the [education](/questions/tagged/education) from the two questions in question.

As Sha Wiz Dow Ward pointed out, posting here is the correct thing to do.

Comment: While we're on the subject, could you remove the training tag from the first question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935951/what-are-some-advanced-software-development-topics-every-developer-should-know

Comment: @Won't what do you suggest I replace it with?

Comment: @ChrisF: Well, I'd suggest deleting it first off.  It's four years old, only has 4k views, and is off topic.  A lock isn't really warranted.  Other than that, the [language-agnostic] tag fits better.

Comment: @Won't Ah. Deleting is certainly a viable option.