# Allow flags on historically locked questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, locked-questions

I came across a historical locked question with bad tagging, and of course couldn't edit it.  I was then going to flag it, but realized that there is no flag link either.  I think we need the flag capability on historical locked questions, so that input can be given to the moderators on it if needed.

Comment: That's odd. I see a flag option underneath this locked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags , but that may be because I'm a moderator. I do see flag options for locked questions on sites where I'm not, though. What does your interface look like for that question?

Comment: @BradLarson, I do see it for that question, here's the one I don't see it for, http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/13295.

Comment: Neither do I. This might be something localized to the circumstances of that question.

Comment: @BradLarson I tried putting it in all sorts of different states (opened, closed, protected, etc.) and the flag link seems to always disappear on that question as soon as I put the lock back on.

Comment: It's a historical lock. You can't flag historical locks. That was part of the points of historical locks: there's no way to dispute anything about them.

Comment: The other (non-historical) lock on @Brad's link is a "high amount of off-topic comments" lock. There's also a "locked while disputes are resolved" ([deleted example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220576/my-accounts-applications-have-been-disabled-with-no-explanation)). Historical locks seem to be the only type of lock that disallows flagging. See also [Can't flag historically locked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190360/cant-flag-historically-locked-questions)?

Comment: @apsillers, that is a dupe of a sort, but about a specific instance.  This is a feature-request to fix this.  I'll edit in the information found about historical locks.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I agree -- I've removed the "duplicate" language in my comment. I assume the no-flag behavior on historically locked questions is to stop users from mindlessly flagging them as off-topic (since it is already known and accepted that they are off-topic). I'd guess the mods found the harm caused by disallowing flagging (i.e., you have to make a request on Meta) is rare a minor enough that it outweighed the extra volume of erroneous flags. There *might* be some sort of compromise possible here, but I'm not sure. Maybe only allow high-rep users to flag historical questions?

Comment: Yeh, it seems like just allowing 20k+ would suffice (which wouldn't have helped me in this case, but is a reasonable compromise).

Comment: @Gilles:  That seems short-sighted to me.  The rules that govern what is on-/off-topic at SO have evolved greatly over the years.  How can we know now that *every* historically locked question will *never* be on-topic again?