# How to treat old locked questions containing outdated information?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, locked-questions, historical-lock

Suppose an old closed question has an historical lock on it, making impossible to vote/comment/flag on any post.

What should we do if such questions have a high visibility but contains *some* outdated or wrong information? [What if the answers of a historical locked question become obsolete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/what-if-the-answers-of-a-historical-locked-question-become-obsolete#156226) indicates that such questions should be unlocked (and potentially removed), but what about cases where *most* of the information is still accurate and useful?

For instance:

[What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)

I think this post still deserves a historical lock as the information provided is indeed useful. Only little parts of it are gradually becoming outdated and still being hit every time one queries for *cocoa best practices*.

What should we do when a historical-locked question provides, say 85% of useful up-to-date information and 15% of outdated one?

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for pointing me to the duplicate question. I'll put a bounty on it since the accepted answer doesn't consider the case in which a locked post contains mostly useful information and only a few parts are outdated.

Comment: I've linked to a longer answer, but the short version is: if it reaches the point where it's no longer useful, post a request here & we'll remove it. Until then, try your best to scavenge any useful information for use in less broad, subjective questions... Or even move them [into a tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocoa/info).

Comment: Eh... Don't bounty it; if the solution presented on that question doesn't work for a given scenario, explain why and propose a better solution. You could do this in either an answer on that question, or an entirely new question.

Comment: @Shog9 clear. Still that question is being hit by the *Cocoa best practices* query as first result and it's providing **some** outdated information. I think we should do something like marking it as outdated or at least being able to propose edits to keep the information fresh.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't have a better solution actually, should I go ahead and explain my concerns modifying this question?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. FWIW: the big problem with that question is that it has 33 answers... And stands a really good chance of ending up with more if it's unlocked. Folks might be convinced to keep one or two answers up-to-date, but it's pretty unlikely anyone wants to babysit a few dozen. That's why I would strongly suggest moving the good parts to a wiki, where folks can update it as they see fit.

Comment: @Shog9 Done. I don't think the post should be unlocked either, but there should probably be a way of proposing edits even to a locked answer.

Comment: The problem is that if it can *change* then it isn't really *locked* anymore - it stops being a historical artifact and starts being a living document. That's not a bad thing, but it is something *different*. FWIW, I'm occasionally experimenting with [a 3rd option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572) for questions that have a single (or at least a reasonable number) of wiki *answers* - however, that wouldn't work here.

Comment: I see, yes it's indeed an issue and that's why I would like to see it discussed. Right now we have [SO] providing outdated information in posts with an extremely high visibility and we don't have a strategy for dealing with them.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the edit, much better!