# Allow flags on locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, locked-questions

There are historically locked posts (such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/9805/255683)) containing offensive answers (such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/20301/255683)).

I am not interested in flagging the question for deletion -- a moderator already decided that it's a bad question that should stay anyway. But being locked doesn't mean the answers are all "not offensive" or even "not spam".

**I propose that locked posts lose their immunity to spam, offensive, and custom-reason flags.**

Comment: I don't find the BOFH offensive ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This only applies to historical locks, and it's very much intentional: before this was built into the system, such questions would *repeatedly* get flagged.

The whole point is that they're capturing an artifact of the past, frozen in time, for the enjoyment of future historians but no longer an active part of the site. So allowing flags makes no sense: if we're gonna *change* anything, then it shouldn't be locked, at least not with the Historical lock. Museums don't put little bells next to each painting to summon a censor in the event that someone gets upset about something in them...

If you see something in a locked post that you feel is a **serious** problem, bring it up on the per-site meta. Folks can discuss it and decide what to do. Otherwise, move on.

#### See also: [What if the answers of a historical locked question become obsolete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/what-if-the-answers-of-a-historical-locked-question-become-obsolete)

Comment: Just FYI, comments on that locked post can be flagged still, just not the answers. Is that an inconsistency? (I just flagged a comment as chatty.. apparently successfully).

Comment: @rolfl I think you found a nice backdoor (I plan to use it; in the past there were 2 or 3 cases when I had to use much more complicated schemes to flag through into a locked question)

Comment: See also: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (111 flags)

Answer (score 6):

If a question is historically locked, it means a moderator locked that post. A moderator will scan the question / answer before doing that (if not, adjust procedure).

I think there is no real need to go over that post again and again. If there is something wrong, just flag one of your own posts and link to that question/answer telling what is wrong. Maybe, if you want to discuss it, raise a question on the site's meta.