# Let us delete our own comments even if the post is locked

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-delete, locked-questions

I tried to delete a comment I posted, and got the "Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting" error.

The lock in that case is of type "locked while disputes about its content are being resolved", so while it's useful to prevent edits and new comments, I can't see why not allow users to delete their existing comments there, since moderators will still be able to see the deleted comments, so users can't hide their actions or bad behavior.

So can we please get the ability to delete our comments even under locked posts?

Comment: And why would you get a message about voting when you're trying to delete a comment?

Comment: @Snow oh, that's fine, it's because deletion is done by using a delete vote; in case it's your own question/answer/comment, that single vote is binding.

Comment: @Snow Internally, deleting a comment is considered a "vote".

Comment: I assume this would exclude historical locks. I don't think this change would be necessarily bad, but it seems somehow strange to say "All interactions with a locked post are forbidden, except for moderator flags and deleting your own comment". I mean, everyone can understand why it should still be possible to flag a locked post, but deleting your comments? That somehow seems off. :/

Comment: I can't delete my comment on a locked question too. And there is no flagging available to ask for a moderator intervention.

Comment: @OlivierRogier post means either a question or an answer, so it's included in my request. And as for not being able to flag, it's because it's a rare lock called "historical lock" and a request to allow flagging was declined: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247501/allow-flags-on-locked-posts.

Comment: Lies, attacks and degrading comments as well as insults can't be flagged for administrator intervention if a question is locked and will remain as-is until a power user will read it and decide to delete it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier no. Even power user can't delete or even flag it. In those cases, you can either flag a different, not related, post and explain in the "Other" field what you want, or post a meta question. Either way, moderators will see it and will be able to remove those comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou if you can see a deleted question/answer, I suppose you can flag the post itself with a custom mod flag and explain you want a comment under it removed. Still, I agree that I believe we *should* be able to delete our comments. I run into this now on a deleted (and locked) post - I wanted to remove a comment from it but I got "Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting" as well. Which seems weird - I should be able to remove my own comments from there.

Comment: @VLAZ exactly the reasoning for this request. (your last sentence)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou yep, I was going to file a FR myself but found yours and upvoted it.